# Extending c3js with d3js code

Tags: d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, c3.js

i am new to c3js, so apologies if this question sounds basic. The c3js library seems to be very powerful yet there are some features in d3js currently not available in c3js which I plan to use inside my c3js code. Does anyone has any experience in using d3js code with c3js or using d3js inside or c3js code.
For reference, I plan to use the click functions present in d3js on my visualizations built in c3js.

thanks

Comment: I haven't used C3.js personally, but assuming that it leaves all of its generated content as svg elements then it would be easy enough to do a `d3.selectAll(...).on("click", function)` command to bind click events. However it would most likely require decent understanding of the C3 library for more complex interaction. For example, if C3.js does something with bound data that makes it less accessible, simple operations could become far more complex. If what you're doing isn't too in-depth then you may be better off developing from scrach in D3 (obviously this will take significantly longer).

Comment: c3.js is actually built on top of d3js and all c3.js code is d3js internally.
Yes, you can customize c3js by overriding certain internal functions if the config is not readily available.
Please refer to c3.js google discussion forum for some examples:- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/c3js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can access the c3 chart elements using the classes that c3 uses (you can find the full list of classes in the source at https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/blob/master/c3.js#L5754), this probably wouldn't be the right way to attach any click handlers - the reason being that c3 charts are rendered in layers and your click event may not actually be triggered because it's used by a layer that comes above.

For instance, while

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    }
});

d3.selectAll('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.bar + ':nth-child(2)').attr('display', 'none');
```

would be a good way of hiding the 2nd set of data points, you can't use the same to attach a click handler for the 2nd set of data points.

The right way to do this would be to use data.onclick that c3 provides - see http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onRendered function to write d3.js code 
check the [reference from c3.js](https://c3js.org/reference.html#onrendered) reference page

**Note:** if you are using angular 2+ you should use arrow function instead of function with key work 'function'

```
`var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ]
    },
    onrendered: function () {
        // d3 code - click functionality
    }
});
`
```

Also, c3 has onclick functionality that you can modify and re utilize. for reference [check this](https://c3js.org/reference.html#data-onclick)

Elaborate the functionality that you want to implement, wo that you canget better solution